# C++ 64bit page faults

Tags: c++

I have a C++ server application running on Windows Server 2003 64 bit. Machine has 16 cores and 16 GB of ram. Once the app gets to about 2GB memory usage its Page Fault delta shoots up to ~200,000 and the app becomes very slow. The app is compiled with a 64bit compiler. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does GetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx indicate a maximum working set of 2GB? If so, raise it with SetProcessWorkingSizeEx.